# skimage.transform.rotate: getting a completely black image on saving

Tags: python, rotation, scikit-image

I am working with python 3.6 and performing following functions on an image (read image, pad image, crop image, rotate image). I am either using skimage or basic python function. If I don't rotate the image then there is no warning. But if I rotate the image, I am getting following warning

> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/util/dtype.py:122:
>   UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from int64 to
>   float64 .format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))

When I try to view the image using imshow, image values seemed to be in the range of (1e-17) (https://ibb.co/cSfzb7). I guess image values got normalized somewhere but I am not able to find the location.

If I try to save the rotated image, I get a completely black image.

```
im = img_as_uint(image)
imsave(image_path, im, plugin='imageio')
```

I tried removing img_as_uint, using default imsave, using (freeimage, imagio) as plugin option

> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/util/dtype.py:122:
>   UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from int64 to
>   float64 .format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/util/dtype.py:122:
>   UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from float64 to
>   uint16 .format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/io/_io.py:132:
>   UserWarning: /Users/ashisharora/google_Drive/madcat_arabic/lines/AAW_ARB_20061105.0017-S1_1_LDC0372_00z1.png is a low contrast image warn('%s is a low contrast image' % fname)

```
import sys
import argparse
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import skimage
from skimage.io import imread, imsave, imshow
from skimage.transform import rotate
from skimage import img_as_uint

im_wo_pad = imread(image_file_name) 
im = pad_image(im_wo_pad) 
region_initial = im[281:480, 2509:4766] 
rotation_angle_in_rad = -0.00708 
img2 = rotate(region_initial, degrees(rotation_angle_in_rad)) 
region_final = img2[15:298, 7:2263] 
imshow(region_final)


def pad_image(image):
    offset = 200
    max_val = 255
    height = image.shape[0]
    im_pad = np.concatenate((max_val * np.ones((height, offset),
                                        dtype=int), image), axis=1)
    im_pad1 = np.concatenate((im_pad, max_val * np.ones((height, offset),
                                                 dtype=int)), axis=1)

    width = im_pad1.shape[1]

    im_pad2 = np.concatenate((max_val * np.ones((offset, width),
                                         dtype=int), im_pad1), axis=0)
    im_pad3 = np.concatenate((im_pad2, max_val * np.ones((offset, width),
                                                  dtype=int)), axis=0)
    return im_pad3
```

I tried solutions posted on stack overflow but it is not working for my case. I would appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 7):

By default, the skimage rotate function converts to float and scales the image values between 0 and 1. (See http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rotate)

Try using the preserve_range parameter and some type casting, e.g.,

```
img_rot = skimage.transform.rotate(img, rot_angle, preserve_range=True).astype(np.uint8)
```